# Populate Word document with large text

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to populate Word document with the replacement text which is too big to put in. Could someone help me? I am trying for hours and could not found a working method.

My code:

```
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim lastCol As Integer

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim wApp As Object
Dim wDoc As Word.Document

Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

wApp.Visible = True

For srow = 2 To lastRow
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\Temp\Template.docx")
    For scol = 1 To lastCol
        With wDoc.Content.Find
            .Text = "$" & ActiveSheet.Cells(1, scol) & "$"
            ***.Replacement.Text = ActiveSheet.Cells(srow, scol)*** 'This is where the code stops. Thats too big.
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    Next
    wApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs "C:\Temp\1.class\" & ActiveSheet.Cells(srow, 1) & ".docx"
Next
```

Comment: How big is the text? If it is way tooooo big then one other way would be `find` the text, select it and then use `wApp.Selection.Range.text = ActiveSheet.Cells(srow, scol).Value` :)

Comment: Not sure why the close vote here?

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error message that you get at the marked line?

Answer (score 0):

Word Find & Replace expressions cannot be longer than 255 characters. Try something along the lines of:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, sRow As Long, sCol As Long
Dim xlSht As Worksheet, wdApp As Object, wdDoc As Object
Dim StrFnd As String, StrRep As String

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set xlSht = ActiveSheet
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

With wdApp
  .Visible = True
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open("C:\Temp\Template.docx", , False, False, , , , , , , , False)
  With wdDoc
    For sRow = 2 To lastRow
      For sCol = 1 To lastCol
        StrFnd = "$" & xlSht.Cells(1, sCol).Text & "$"
        StrRep = xlSht.Cells(sRow, sCol).Text
        If Len(StrRep) < 256 Then
          .Range.Find.Execute StrFnd, StrRep, , , , , , 1, , , 2
        Else
          With .Range
            With .Find
              .Text = StrFnd
              .Replacement.Text = StrRep
              .Wrap = 0
              .Execute
            End With
            Do While .Find.Found = True
              .Text = StrFnd
              .Collapse 0
              .Find.Execute
            Loop
          End With
        End If
      Next
      .SaveAs "C:\Temp\1.class\" & ActiveSheet.Cells(sRow, 1).Text & ".docx"
    Next
  End With
  .Quit
End With
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set xlSht = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I get run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument         The line .Range.Find.Execute StrFnd, StrRep, .....  I do not exactly understand what some of the lines used to do :(

Comment: Code corrected. To understand what a given line does, check the Excel or Word entry, as appropriate, in the VBA help file for the method concerned.